# how to extract column parameters from sqlite create string?

Tags: regex, sqlite

in sqlite it is possible to have string by which the table was created:

```
select sql from sqlite_master where type='table' and tbl_name='MyTable'
```

this could give:

```
CREATE TABLE "MyTable" (`id` PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, [col1] NOT NULL,
 "another_col" UNIQUE, '`and`,''another'',"one"' INTEGER, and_so_on);
```

Now I need to extract with this string any additional parameters that given column name has been set with.

But this is very difficult since the column name could be enclosed with special characters, or put plain, column name may have some special characters that are used as encapsulation etc.

I don't know how to approach it. The result should be having a column name the function should return anything that is after this name and before `,` so giving it `id` it should return `PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL`.

Comment: Look answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730342/sql-command-to-extract-schema-of-a-sqlite-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pragma table_info:

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info

```
sqlite> pragma table_info(MyTable);
cid|name|type|notnull|dflt_value|pk
0|id||1||1
1|col1||1||0
2|another_col||0||0
3|`and`,'another',"one"|INTEGER|0||0
4|and_so_on||0||0
```